# Output routine footbib error

Tags: errors, memoir, footbib

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,
            linktocpage=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            filecolor=black,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=black,
}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{footbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\copypagestyle{ruledsmallhd}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruledsmallhd}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruledsmallhd}{}{}{\footnotesize\scshape\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{ruledsmallhd}{0px}{0px}
```

And this is the error I get when I compile:

```
! Package footbib Error: the output routine of LaTeX changed.
```

What does it mean, and why is it happening?

Comment: what it means is that footbib wants to patch a standard latex output routine, and it finds that memoir has already patched it.  one of the two has to give: either you have memoir or you have footbib.  (unfortunately memoir doesn't emulate footbib ... it emulates a lot of others, but not footbib.)  fwiw, you have the same problem with scrartcl, so that's not a way out.

Comment: @anon: Go ahead and add that as an answer!

Comment: bother: scrub that -- i went to work to get something more modern, but the only available machine is (i now realise) running a linux that's still using tetex ... can't get to my own machine with tl11 on it (can't switch it on from here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the `footbib` package, on page 8, notes that it "does not work with most packages which modify the output routine of LaTeX: `multicol`, `ftnright`, `floatflt`, `wrapfig`, etc." The package therefore does a number of (fairly) elaborate tests to check whether the output routine has been modified, and it issues a warning/error message when the tests turn out positive -- this is what you're encountering.

What to do? The full error message -- a warning message, really -- generated by the package suggests to:

- Send an email to `Eric.Domenjoud@loria.fr` to get a new version (of `footbib`), and
- Type X < return > to quit or *cross your fingers and just type < return >* [emphasis added]

In sum, there's a chance that, whatever modifications to the output routine that `memoir` undertakes, these modifications may not be sufficiently important to mess up `footbib`. You won't know until you actually give it a try.

Comment: So far I have gotten an error, it doesn't seem to read the `.bib` file or the entry corresponding to the keyword. I suppose I'll have to read the documentation one more time to make sure it's not related the `memoir` package.

Comment: The `memoir` document class emulates lots of LaTeX packages that are out there, and one or more of memoir's components must be modifying the output routine. It's probably not so much a bug in `memoir` per se, but a matter of various packages relying on special modifications of the output routines that end up being incompatible with each other. :-(

Comment: So is there any other package with the same functionality as `footbib` that does not clash with `memoir`? It's much easier to change `footbib` than `memoir`.