# Switching from memoir to report

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr, report

I've been using `memoir` for a while now, and have started facing problems with [modified output routine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45190/output-routine-footbib-error), this has forced me to seriously consider switching (back) to `report` class. What I'm going to ask might seem like a case of "Do the research for me", so I hope I'm not asking for too much. I would like to know how to produce 'exactly' the same output with `report` given the following:

The preamble (up until now of course) `Preamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex,
            linktocpage=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            filecolor=black,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=black}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{calc}
\copypagestyle{ruledsmallhd}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruledsmallhd}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruledsmallhd}{}{}{\footnotesize\scshape\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{ruledsmallhd}{0px}{0px}
```

The main file:

```
\input{Preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruledsmallhd}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\newpage
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\subimport{./Chapter1/}{Chapter1.tex}
\subimport{./Chapter2/}{Chapter2.tex}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{./Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

I think the obvious issue is producing exactly the same headers/footers with `fancyhdr` instead of `pagestyle`, but of course I wouldn't really know what else would change, hence I've posted this question.

Comment: You may want to explain in more detail which features of the `memoir` document class you want to retain after switching to `report` (or `book`, or whatever). Many -- but certainly not all! -- features embedded in the `memoir` document class can be replicated by loading various and sundry LaTeX packages.

Comment: @Mico Like I said, I wouldn't really know, although basically I would like to retain ToC/LoF/LoT style, page layout and header/footer setup, including pagination.

Comment: Please see my answer for some suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to use the `book` class and the following setup for `fancyhdr`

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
}
```

and then

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{frontmatter}
\maketitle
\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtableename}
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

...

\end{document}
```

You might need to change some pagination parameters, use `geometry`.

Answer (score 3):

My inclination would be not to give up prematurely on the `memoir` class, especially as it may be possible to figure out which parts are giving you problems because of interference with the output routine.

Quoting from p. xxix of [The Memoir Class](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), the user guide to the `memoir` document class:

> The memoir class includes code either equivalent to, or extensions of, the following packages; that is, the set of commands and environments is at least the same as those in the packages: abstract, appendix, array, booktabs, ccaption, chngcntr, chngpage, dcolumn, delarray, enumerate, epigraph, framed, ifmtarg, ifpdf, index, makeidx, moreverb, needspace, newfile, nextpage, parskip, patchcmd, setspace, shortvrb, showidx, tabularx, titleref, titling, tocbibind, tocloft, verbatim, verse.

Most of these packages do *not* modify the output routine. If you can figure out which packages are the ones that are giving you trouble, you could issue the following commands -- picking the packages `chngpage` and `nextpage` purely for sake of illustration:

```
\DisemulatePackage{chngpage}
\DisemulatePackage{nextpage}
```

Quoting some more from the manual:

> The [memoir] class also provides functions similar to those provided by the following packages, although the commands are different: crop, fancyhdr, geometry, sidecap, subfigure, titlesec. You can use these packages if you wish, or just use the capabilities of the memoir class.

AFAICT, this is the exhaustive list of all LaTeX packages emulated by or incorporated in `memoir`.