# Which memoir package emulation clashes with footbib?

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, output-routine, footbib

`memoir` has at least one package that modifies the output routine and conflicts with `footbib`, does anyone know which one(s)?

Comment: Memoir has no packages, memoir include functionality of various packages, and afterwards tell LaTeX that these has been `emulated` and thus LaTeX should not load them if the user ask for them. But in relation to your question, `memoir` itself change the output routine in various ways.

Comment: BTW doesn't `biblatex` have support for this without the use of footbib?

Comment: @daleif: I believe the OP *meant* to ask whether it's possible, by issuing one or more `\DisemulatePackage{<packagename>}` commands, to get rid of the conflict between `footbib` and `memoir` stemming from their modifications to the output routine. I.e., which packages need to be dis-emulated in order to get `footbib` to work when used inside the `memoir` document class?

Comment: @mico, of course not, as I mentioned, `memoir` itself change the output routine. And `\DisemulatePackage` only mean the package can be loaded, it does not change any changes to the output routine that memoir has already done.

Comment: @daleif Well that changes things. This truly is a predicament now. Any suggestions for the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45190/output-routine-footbib-error   ?

Comment: Doesn't biblatex provide something similar without the use of footbib. But in general, there will always be packages and classes that are incompatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Derived from the comments of daleif)

`memoir` includes the functionality of various packages, and tells LaTeX that these have been emulated and thus LaTeX should not load them if the user asks for them. With regard to the OP's question: `memoir` itself changes the output routine in various ways. `\DisemulatePackage` only allows the respective package to be loaded -- the command cannot undo changes to the output routine that `memoir` has already effected; therefore, one cannot get rid of a conflict between, e.g., `footbib` and `memoir` stemming from their modifications to the output routine.